# re.sub() not working as I expect

Tags: python, regex

I have a string given below.

```
AppCodename: Mozilla<br>Appversion: 5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/41.0.2272.76 Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36<br>
```

I want to extract `Mozilla` from the above string. I use the following python program.

```py
import re
import json

with open('data.txt','rb') as f:                                                                                                                                                               
    data = json.load(f)
    message = data['Message']
    appcodename = re.sub('.+AppCodename: ([^<br>])(.*)',r'\1',message,1)
    print('appcode name {}'.format(appcodename))
```

The output that I get is

```
appcode name M
```

What is wrong with my regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your regex is twofold:

1. You are using a negated class `[^<br>]` which matches any character except `<`, `b`, `r` and `>` (their order is irrelevant). This does not cause any problem with this particular case, but it is not advised to use a negated class to prevent matches for specific sequence of characters.
2. You want `([^<br>])` which can match only 1 character to match `Mozilla` which is several characters long.

Quick & dirty fix:

```
appcodename = re.sub('.*AppCodename: ([^<br>]+)(.*)',r'\1',message,1)
```

`.*` allows matches if the string begins with `AppCodename` and `([^<br>]+)` allows matching of more than one character.

As I mentioned above, the negated character class is not advised. Thus, this is the next step to make the above better:

```
appcodename = re.sub(r'.*AppCodename: ((?:(?!<br>).)+).*',r'\1',message,1)
```

`(?:(?!<br>).)+` is a bit slow (this uses a negative lookahead `(?! ... )`), but it will match any number of characters as long as `<br>` is not within those characters. It is basically checking each character, and each time, it makes sure there is no `<br>` at that character before attempting to match it. Next, rawing a regex string is always advised to avoid unexpected behaviours.

Finally, replacing before and after is not very practical; matching would make things much simpler:

```
appcodename = re.search(r'AppCodename: ((?:(?!<br>).)+)', message).group(1)
```

At that point, you might use something like that instead, which does not use the negative lookahead and much simpler to read I believe:

```
appcodename = re.search(r'AppCodename: (.+?)<br>', message).group(1)
```

Comment: what does (?:) indicate before the negative look ahead?

Comment: @liv2hak This is bascially the same as a normal `( ... )` group. `( ... )` is a capture group while `(?: ... )` is a non-capture group. The difference is that you would use `(?: ... )` if you need a group but don't really need what it will contain. A small example is if you want to match `buses` or `bus` within a larger pattern. `(bus(?:es)?)` would suit your needs and produces the right output while `bus(es)?` would produce 2 outputs: `buses` or `bus`, and `es` if it is present. That extra output on a large scale will slow things down and eat up processing memory.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider matching alot easier than replacing:

```
appcodename = re.search('AppCodename: (\w+)', message).group(1)
print('appcode name {}'.format(appcodename))
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/356149)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `regex`:

```
# match anything after AppCodename: and before <br>.
'.*AppCodename: ([\w]+?)<br>(.*)'
```

Output:

```
appcode name Mozilla
```

Comment: A few things - first `([^<br>])` doesn't make sense. `[]` defines a character class and there is no ordering inside of a character class - `([^b<>r])` means the same thing. You are saying don't match any of those 4 characters, but you should instead be saying match any word characters `([\w]+)` in front of `<br>`

Comment: If I were to replace [\w] with (.*) it doesn't seem to work for reason.why is that ? (.*) is a superset of [\w]

Comment: Yes, but then you are getting everything, including spaces. [\w]+ will stop at the next space.

Comment: but it doens't stop at <br> for some reason.